# Unable to find signing.gradle, please replace Android buildTypes > signing configs with your own configuration

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to build Alexa Android app which i got from github ...But its showing eroor "Unable to find signing.gradle, please replace Android buildTypes > signing configs with your own configuration."
this is the github link:-https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid

And its showing error from build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


if (file('signing.gradle').exists()) {
apply from: 'signing.gradle'
}else{
throw new TaskExecutionException(null, new Exception("Unable to find 
signing.gradle, please replace Android buildTypes > signing configs with 
your own configuration."));
}

 android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.willblaschko.android.alexavoicelibrary"
    minSdkVersion 21

    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 5
    versionName "2.1.1"
    multiDexEnabled true;
}


buildTypes {
    debug{
        versionNameSuffix " Debug"
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile project(path: ':libs:AlexaAndroid')
compile project(path: ':libs:RecorderLevelView')
compile project(path: ':libs:speechutils-master')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines

```
if (file('signing.gradle').exists()) {
    apply from: 'signing.gradle'
} else {
    throw new TaskExecutionException(null, new Exception("Unable to find signing.gradle, please replace Android buildTypes > signing configs with your own configuration."));
}
```

with your signingConfigs generated while implementing LWA:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        auto_sign {
            keyAlias ''
            keyPassword ''
            storeFile file('C:/Users/UserName/.android/keystore.jks')
            storePassword ''
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I am also facing the same issues. The new Amazon alexa SDK now comes with secuity profile id, client id,client secret and refresh token. Now how shall I modify signingconfigs?